# Python. Catching error without try... except

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, error-handling

So I build a small logger class that logs everything but there is a small issue with it.
Then some kind of exception/error happens outside of `try... except` block I don't have a way to log it into a file.
So the question is, how to catch errors out side of `try... except` block.
Also if there someone saying "Put whole program in try except.", well here is the problem that it completely ignores errors happening in threads and subprocesses.
Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import logging


class Msg:
    def __init__(self, logger_name, path, conn=None, info_format="utf-8", file_name=None):
        self.path = path
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.now = datetime.now()
        self.now = self.now.strftime("%d_%m_%Y-%H_%M_%S")
        self.file_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(message)s")
        if file_name is not None:
            self.now = file_name
        self.file_handler = logging.FileHandler(f"{self.path}/{self.now}.log")
        self.file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.file_handler.setFormatter(self.file_formatter)
        self.stream_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s:%(message)s")
        self.stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        self.stream_handler.setFormatter(self.stream_formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.stream_handler)
        self.logger.addHandler(self.file_handler)
        
    def debug(self, message):
        self.logger.debug(message)

    def info(self, message):
        self.logger.info(message)

    def warning(self, message):
        self.logger.warning(message)

    def error(self, message):  # Somehow any exception outside try except have to trigger this to be logged or any other function.
        self.logger.error(message, exc_info=True)

    def critical(self, message):
        self.logger.critical(message, exc_info=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    log = Msg("Example_Logger_Name", ".")|
    a = 1/0  # an example error
```

Comment: It goes against the design of an exception model to detect exceptions with anything other than try/except. If you have issues in threads, they can also use try/except. As for subprocesses, they cannot throw exceptions, so you will have to look at the output and/or the return code somehow and decide whether a log message is called for.

Comment: [sys.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) may help.

Comment: Okay, I am gonna check it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher
Documentation says that you can define own handler but there is no example and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: You create a function which takes the same parameters (let's call it "handler") and assign it: `sys.excepthook = handler`.